# CSS how to increase the height bottom upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I am trying to change the CSS of a div when clicked.

This is easily achieved (I am using styled components):

```
height: ${props => (props.isOpen ? '100px' : '')};
```

However, this always changes the box from the top down, i.e. when I click on it the top line of the div remains static and the bottom line moves down so that the new height is achieved.

I want to achieve the reverse of this: the top line moves upwards and the bottom of the div remains in place

How is this achieved in CSS?

Comment: apply negative margin-top with the same value

Comment: Could you please add snippet for more understanding

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the element you want to collapse and increase the height of the parent at the same time that you set a negative `margin-top` of the element itself.

Something like this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.outer').classList.toggle('collapsed');
});
```

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

.outer.collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
  transition: all 5s ease;
}

.outer.collapsed .inner {
  margin-top: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    text<br />
    text<br />
    text<br />
    text<br />
    text<br />
    text<br />
    text final<br />
  </div>
</div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: @donut any thoughts?